# How to add generated column who depends its own?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add a generated column using MYSQL which is basically depends on some other columns as well as on its own in some cases. Is it possible to do that?

Also I am facing some errors while adding a generated column with default value. Here is the command that I am trying:

```sql
ALTER TABLE temp
ADD COLUMN abc INT AS 
(CASE 
    WHEN cde > 95 THEN "1"
    WHEN cde < 80 THEN "0"
    WHEN (cde > 79 AND cde < 96) THEN abc
END) DEFAULT 0
```

Can I achieve something like this with generated column?

Comment: No.  A generated column cannot be self-referential.  You need to create a column with a new name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, now I got what you are trying to do. In case `cde` changes you only want to change `abc` in some cases and in others not.

It is hence not a generated column you are looking for, because such column only depends on the current fields of the row. **You want a trigger** instead that changes or not changes `abc` depending on the new value of `cde`.

Have a look at the docs on how to write such trigger: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

> In a BEFORE trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. This means you can use a trigger to modify the values to be inserted into a new row or used to update a row. (Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger because the row change will have already occurred.)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't make a generated column reference itself.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html says:

> A generated column definition can refer to other generated columns, but only those occurring earlier in the table definition.

Since a generated column always takes its value from the expression referencing other columns, it doesn't make any sense to give it a DEFAULT clause.

To do what you're describing you could do it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE temp
ADD COLUMN abc INT AS 
(CASE 
    WHEN cde > 95 THEN "1"
    WHEN cde < 80 THEN "0"
    WHEN (cde > 79 AND cde < 96) THEN 0
END)
```

Comment: OK, I got it, a generated column can not be self-referential. but if I don't give a DEFAULT clause in command like ```ALTER TABLE temp
ADD COLUMN abc INT AS 
(CASE 
    WHEN cde > 95 THEN "1"
    WHEN cde < 80 THEN "0"
END) NOT NULL```  how the mysql will manage to not null in case `cde` between 80 and 95? and also above solution is not correct. I want to set the `abc` 1 if `cde` has ever touched 95 or more before in case if `cde` is now between 80 and 95 else 0.

Comment: Have you seen the `ELSE` clause of the `CASE` syntax? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html